# Cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent error not resolved

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, http-headers

This method is exporting the datatable into excel

```
  public static void ExportToExcel(DataTable table)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(@"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"">");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Reports.xls");

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "utf-8";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250");
                //sets font
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<font style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Calibri;'>");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<BR><BR><BR>");
                //sets the table border, cell spacing, border color, font of the text, background, foreground, font height
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Table border='1' bgColor='#ffffff' " +
                                                   "borderColor='#000000' cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0' " +
                                                   "style='font-size:11.0pt; font-family:Calibri; background:white;'> <TR>");
                //am getting my grid's column headers
                int columnscount = table.Columns.Count;

                for (int j = 0; j < columnscount; j++)
                {
                    //write in new column
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Td>");
                    //Get column headers  and make it as bold in excel columns
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<B>");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(table.Columns[j].ToString());
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</B>");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Td>");
                }
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</TR>");
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
//write in new row
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<TR>");
                    for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Td>");
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(row[i].ToString()));
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Td>");
                    }

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</TR>");
                }
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Table>");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</font>");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string abc = ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

This is my controller

```
 public ActionResult ExportData()
        {
            var industryData = _rawDataHlper.GetIndustryData();
            if (industryData != null)
            {
                ExportToExcel((industryData));
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

This method is getting records from the database

```
 public DataTable GetIndustryData()
        {     
            IList<v_IndustryDetail> industryData = _insurancedb.v_IndustryDetail.OrderByDescending(x=>x.ReportYear).ToList();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            return dt;

        }
```

I am getting "cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent" error. I want to redirect to Index action. I have tried searching this error and tried different solutions like instead of

```
Response.End()
```

Use

```
HttpContext.Response.SuppressContent = true;
HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Also tried clearing the header

```
Response.ClearHeaders();
```

But no solution is working and I am getting the same error.

Can anyone help me how to solve this. i have spend nearly a day to fix this but still struggling. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have already send something to response. what do you have in _rawDataHlper.GetIndustryData() ?

Comment: This is a datatable function which is getting result from database. I am passing that datatable into Export to excel function. How can I resolve this. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe you sending the HTTP headers from this function.

Comment: sorry which function?....

Comment: _rawDataHlper.GetIndustryData()

Comment: no this is simple getting records from db I have updated my question and added this function as well

Comment: Did you try to add "return null;" instead of "return RedirectToAction("Index");" in "ActionResult ExportData()"

Comment: well return null will not redirect to the Index action.

Comment: It's just to check if you send the header twice from there. In RedirectToAction() you will send again the HTTP header and you can not as you already sent it before.

Comment: so how should i redirect to the index?

Comment: You can try to add in Your ExportToExcel Function : Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "0;URL=/index"); and "return null;" instead of "return RedirectToAction("Index");"

Comment: Now i am getting Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do that so don't waste your time. What you need to do is to include a cookie and on the client side look for the cookie and then redirect. [Here] (http://gruffcode.com/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser/)  is an example of how to do it with a cookie.

Once you add the headers for download, you can not then set the headers for redirect.